# Which certificate files need to be passed to gunicorn for https?

Tags: linux, gunicorn

I have the following files:
private.key, example.com.pem, example.com.crt, example.com.pem-full-chain,
example.com.p7b and server.csr

I am starting gunicorn using :

> gunicorn -b example.com:5000 'app:create_app()' --certfile=example.com.crt --keyfile=private.key

Nothing seems to work, everytime I get the invalid certificate warning when I go to https://example.com:5000

Comment: Showing the exact error message would be helpful.